# How to provide allowDiskUse : true option with pipeline of JavaMongoRDD in Java code or any other better approach

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I am facing the issue "exception: Exceeded memory limit, Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in." for the example code

> JavaMongoRDD aggregatedRdd = rdd
>       .withPipeline(Arrays.asList(Document.parse(aggregateQuery),
>                                   Document.parse("{$sort: {gatewaytime : -1}")));

There are many examples to pass the allowDiskUse:true in mongo db aggregate() method or via mongo client in java.

I did't found any example or help how to pass these type of options using Spark RDD.withPipeline() method or there is any alternate approach better than using allowDiskUse:true.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sampat please add a ticket to: http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SPARK

Comment: Hi Ross , ticket as SPARK-81 - How to provide allowDiskUse : true option with pipeline of JavaMongoRDD in Java code or any other better approach
is added to jira.mongodb.org/browse/SPARK